# Django model: forbid states with particular values

Tags: django

I wonder if Django offers this feature some other web frameworks like Ruby on Rails do. I am talking about means to forbid certain states where the values of the attributes being saved, for example:

```
model.active = False
model.authorized = True
model.save() # this should fail
```

We can have a `model` where both `active` and `authorized` are either both `True` or `False`, but we cannot have any other combination. Sorry but I can't think of a better example right now, I hope the intent is understood.

So, does Django have any means for handling these situations? Or implementing it ourselves when the method `save` is called is the only way?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the save method on your model.

```
class TestModel(models.Model):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.active == False and self.authorized == True:
            raise ValidationError("Some descriptive text here")
        else:
            return super(TestModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

That's the simplest method to do this, but not the best.

You can also do model validation overriding the `clean` method, but then `full_clean` must be called explicitly before calling save if not using this through a `ModelForm`

The third method applies only if you're using a form to accept the changes, in which case you can override `clean` as above, but the model's `full_clean` is the form's `clean` methods are called when the form's `is_valid` method is called.

Comment: Not all views would be able to [handle the validation errors](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8771090/1324033). Clean methods would be the correct way to go though