# Only allow filling one field or the other in Django model and admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I've got a simple Django model for a **Group** that has a list of **Contacts**. Each group must  have *either* a **Primary contact** `ForeignKey` or a **All contacts** `BooleanField` selected but not both and not none.

```py
class Group(models.Model):
    contacts = models.ManyToManyField(Contact)
    contact_primary = models.ForeignKey(Contact, related_name="contact_primary", null=True)
    all_contacts = models.BooleanField(null=True)
```

How can I ensure that:

1. The model can't be saved unless either `contact_primary` or `all_contacts` (but not both) is set. I guess that would be by implementing the `Group.save()` method? Or should it be the `Group.clean()` method??
2. In Django Admin either disable the other field when one is selected or at least provide a meaningful error message if both or none are set and the admin tries to save it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to override the `save()` method of your model:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    contacts = models.ManyToManyField(Contact)
    contact_primary = models.ForeignKey(Contact, related_name="contact_primary", blank=True, null=True)
    all_contacts = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.contact_primary is not None and self.all_contacts is not None:
            raise Exception("some error message here")  
        if self.contact_primary is None and self.all_contacts is None:
            raise Exception("some other error message here")  

        return super().save()
```

Notice that I added `blank=True` to your model fields.  This is necessary if you want to insert null columns through the admin or through a form.

### Update

If you want to raise a `ValidationError`, you **must** raise it from the model's `clean()` method. Otherwise, you will give a 500 error to the client, rather than an error message.

Comment: Actually I now did the same but in `clean()` method and raising `ValidationError()` which seems to works well in the admin interface as well. Feel free to update your answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @KeepLearning The only downside to that is if you somehow end up saving a model *outside* of your admin/form, then the `clean` wouldn't apply.

Comment: Ah, good point. Maybe do it in both clean() and save() then? Or call `clean()` from `safe()` again just in case?

Comment: @KeepLearning Why do you want to call it from `clean`?  You can raise a `ValidationError` from your `save` method.  The only scenario that would be overlooked when using `save` is if you ran a `bulk_insert`, in that case you would need to catch it in the `clean`.

Comment: When I raise ValidationError from `save()` in Admin I get a debug page with Backtrace. When I raise it from `clean()` I get a nice red message box.

Comment: @KeepLearning It looks like you were right in going with `clean`.  [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8771029/raise-a-validation-error-in-a-models-save-method-in-django) says you have to raise the error from your form, instead of from the model.