# Object owner same as Foreignkey object constraint

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

How can one ensure that a foreignkey (Value.user) from one object (Value) corresponds to the foreignkey (Value.userobject) of another foreignkey object (UserObject.user):

> Value.userobject.user == Value.user

```
class UserObject(Model):
    user = ForeignKey(User, on_delete=CASCADE) 
    dummyvalue = DecimalField(max_digits=18, decimal_places=10)


class Value(Model):
    user = ForeignKey(User, on_delete=CASCADE)
    # Ensure the object is owned by user, ie. userobject.user == user..
    userobject = ForeignKey(UserObject, related_name='TheUsersObject', on_delete=CASCADE)
    dummyvalue = DecimalField(max_digits=18, decimal_places=10)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            CheckConstraint(
                name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_same_object_owner",
                check=(
                    Q(
                        ...
                    )
        ]
```

Currently I can think of handling this when processing the request, but would much prefer handling this as a model constraint if possible.

Comment: That's not possible, you can only write checks that span *one* table.

Comment: Thanks Willem! Incredible speed just as the last time :)

Comment: You can `raise ValidationError(errors)` on `def clean(self)`  method. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8771277/842935

Comment: @daniherrera Hmmm.. Tried following it, yielding the following: ```    def clean(self):
        if self.user != self.userobject.user:
            raise ValidationError(_('Operation not owned by user'))```
which didn't work.

Comment: `clan`is just for form validations. If you are saving model out of a form validation or admin you should to override `asve` method to call the validations.